# NSMutableArray wrapped in C++ class

Tags: c++, objective-c, ios, qt, objective-c++

I'm doing some porting from Qt Cocos2d to iOS cocos2d, am using Objective-C++ as the language for minimal efforts, now I'm wrapping the NSMutableArray in a C++ class for easier porting, basically this is my class

QList.h

```
#ifndef QLIST_H
#define QLIST_H

#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

class QList {
    NSMutableArray* List;

public:
    QList();
    ~QList();
    void append(id);
    id at (int i);
    int size();
    bool isEmpty();
    id takeLast();
    id last();
    void prepend(id);
    id takeAt(int i);
    id takeFirst();
    void clear();
};

#endif
```

QList.mm

```
#ifndef QLIST_MM
#define QLIST_MM

#import "QList.h"

QList::QList() {
    List = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
}
QList::~QList() {
    [List autorelease];
    List = nil;
}
void QList::append(id object) {
    [List addObject:object];
}

id QList::at(int i) {
    return [List objectAtIndex:i];
}

int QList::size() {
    return [List count];
}

bool QList::isEmpty() {
    if ([List count] == 0)
        return true;
    return false;
}

id QList::takeLast() {
    id temp = [List lastObject];
    [List removeLastObject];
    return temp;
}

id QList::last() {
    return [List lastObject];
}

void QList::prepend(id object) {
    [List insertObject:object atIndex:0];
}

id QList::takeAt(int i) {
    id temp = [List objectAtIndex:i];
    [List removeObjectAtIndex:i];
    return temp;
}

id QList::takeFirst() {
    return takeAt(0);
}

void QList::clear() {
    [List removeAllObjects];

}

#endif
```

I'm recieving EXC_BAD_SIGNAL on this line

```
    return [List count];
```

Could anyone help me, I much appreciate it, thanks in advance :)

Comment: There's no problem with this, the problem was in this line

    ai_unit.playerP = this;


I was commenting it out until a later time so I can uncomment it, and it was trying to access that :)

Thanks!, if you have advice for this code, let me know :P

Comment: Advice/Warning: Make sure you code does not implicitly copy a `QList` object or you might end up over releasing `List` with out a call to retain in the copy constructor.

Comment: Thank you for the advice, Actually also I have removed the code in the destructor method ~QList because it's causing problems, and added a function called release which after using any QList, I release it manually

Comment: and no, I don't do copying, at least in this app, I always pass as a pointer, if I want to copy, I copy manually using a for loop :)

Comment: The issue might have been that you used `autorelease` instead of `release`. If there is not auto release pool when your `QList` gets destroyed then that would cause problems.

Comment: Yes, I changed that, the issue is solved now :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no problem with this, the problem was in this line

```
ai_unit.playerP = this;
```

I was commenting it out until a later time so I can uncomment it, and it was trying to access that :) Thanks!, if you have advice for this code, let me know :P